# Excel: Summing a column based upon unique values in another column plus additional criterea

Tags: excel, count, sum, sumifs, vba

I am trying to sum a column of numbers only in the instance where I have a unique row (defined by two columns) and only when certain other criteria are met. I am considering something as "unique" based upon the combination of two columns: the ID and Product (see below).

To use an example to illustrate what I am trying to do, I would want the sum for "Number of Days" where a unique value existed (based on ID and Product), and only where "Type" is equal to "Nebula" and "Status" is equal to "Won".

Currently, my only way of doing this is to remove duplicate from my data based upon the ID and Product, and then use a PivotTable and filter to determine the averages.  However, my goal is to be able to write a formula in a cell so that this step is not required.

```
ID | Product   | Type       | Status   | Number of Days | Item
1  | Nebula    | New        | Won      | 3              | Module
1  | Nebula    | New        | Won      | 3              | Mobile
1  | Saturn    | Existing   | Won      | 3              | Module
2  | Nebula    | New        | Won      | 3              | Mobile
2  | Saturn    | Existing   | Won      | 3              | Mobile
3  | Mars      | New        | Lost     | 5              | Module
```

Comment: One method to do so would be to use a helper column and then a sumifs() on the helper column, but I do not see that as much less work or faster than your current method.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,1,B:B,"Product 1",C:C,"Type 1",D:D,"New")
```

EDIT:

Add a helper column that is ID + Product, then use that for the `SUMIF`

```
ID | Product   | Type       | Status   | Number of Days | Item   | Helper
1  | Nebula    | New        | Won      | 3              | Module | 1Nebula
1  | Nebula    | New        | Won      | 3              | Mobile | 1Nebula
1  | Saturn    | Existing   | Won      | 3              | Module | 1Saturn
2  | Nebula    | New        | Won      | 3              | Mobile | 2Nebula
2  | Saturn    | Existing   | Won      | 3              | Mobile | 2Saturn
3  | Mars      | New        | Lost     | 5              | Module | 3Mars
```

In this scenario, you would have a list of the unique labels in the `Helper` column, then use the following `SUMIFS` (assuming the distinct `Helper` list is in Column H)

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,G:G,H:H,B:B,"Nebula",D:D,"Won")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The issue with this approach is that I need the identification of a unique row to be dynamic in the formula. My data set has 1,000 rows with upwards of 800 unique IDs; I can't do this formula 800+ times.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the dataset? Might be as simple as replacing the "Product 1" and "Type 1" etc. fields in the formula with cell references

Comment: Sumifs should be your solution here. You just need to replace TheGuyThatDoesn'tKnowMuch's formula with the references to each of 1, Product 1, Type 1, New, etc.

Comment: Updated the original post with better sample data.  Essentially, within one cell I need to be able to input a formula that will sum the Number of Days column where "Product" is "Nebula", "Status" is "Won", and where there is a unique combination of "ID" and "Product". The originally suggested formula will not work.  As you can see, you can have a product listed multiple times within an ID because it is associated with different items sold (these rows represent sales).  For the purposes of my calculation, the days should only be considered one time per product + ID combination.

Comment: Edited my answer.  You can add a "helper" column that is the combination of ID and Product, then `SUMIFS` using that

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. There is no column H in your example, the helper column is column G. Can you explain further?

Comment: Column H would be a distinct list of what is created in Column G.